# Windows 10 No Internet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-10, router, internet

There's several no "internet" questions on here already, but most of them are a different scenario.

The machine in question here is a Windows 10 Pro, Dell XPS 12, factory specs. It literally can connect to a network, wirelessly with no issues. I can remote desktop into the machine and the machine can talk to other machines and devices on my network, make changes to the router settings, etc.

However, the machine cannot connect to the internet; I thought maybe it was the wireless adapter, blew it away, reinstalled it, tried 3 different driver sets for it, all the same result. I tried a different wi-fi network, same result, other machines, on both networks, can connect to the internet.

At this point, I tried a whole round of things, resetting the TCP/IP stack, resetting internet connection settings, resetting windows (not a full reinstall, just a reset), DHCP cache clearing, DNS flushing, re-registering all the proper windows DLL's, reinstalling windows services, disabling firewall and anti-virus; no luck.

I also tried USB tethering from my phone, which works fine on my other Windows 10 laptop, again, I get a connection to the phone that Windows 10 recognizes, can receive/send files over it, but cannot connect to the internet; same with bluetooth, and the onboard network card, hard-wired in.

So 4 different methods of connecting to the internet, and it can't connect using any of them, but it can connect to other devices and computers, long story short/TLDR, it has LAN access but no WAN access, no matter what I connect to.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the answer was a piece of malware on the computer. The piece of malware was intersecting and hijacking network traffic, but was only smart enough to hijack/disrupt WAN traffic, not LAN traffic.

Answer (score 0):

If you have LAN access, then no matter what, your network card has no problem. Go to `cmd` and ping a well known address:

```
ping 8.8.8.8
```

or

```
ping 4.2.2.4
```

If you can ping them, so I bet it's a DNS problem. Try to add a DNS like `8.8.8.8` manually in your network adapter.

[image]

Comment: Still no go, I cannot ping either address from either network adapter.

Comment: With all of your gateways? phone hotspot and router and...?

Comment: Well, I can ping it, if i don't manually use those as the DNS; if I switch my configuration to a staitc config, from a dynamic and use those, I can't ping anything.

Comment: And the ping I get is not a valid response, its jujst a "transmit failed" general failure

Comment: *"Well, I can ping it, if i don't manually use those as the DNS; if I switch my configuration to a staitc config, from a dynamic and use those, I can't ping anything."*

Do you change both configurations to static? or just the DNS section? look at my screen shot above.

Comment: The fact that you can ping this address, literally means you have WAN access. Do you see "Server not found" error while trying to browse the internet?

Comment: I had changed both, trying just the dns

Comment: Still nothing new

Comment: Have you modified your hosts file? Have you disabled firewall for one of your profiles, or all of them? (e.g. Private, Public, Domain). try to resolve an address by going to `cmd` and executing `nslookup google.com 8.8.8.8` and do this in the situation you can ping `8.8.8.8`. You got my word, it's a DNS problem. Can you please tell me what browser says when it fails to reach the destination address?